# Hide wordpress menu in existing slidetoggle drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a slidetoggle full page drop down menu and am trying to add my registered wordpress menu inside it but I cannot get the list items to not be visible like the box behind them is before clicking on the hamburger icon to reveal it?

```
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header-wrapper">
                <h1 class="logo-text">Sell Garrard 301</h1>
                <div class="hamburger-helper">
                <div id="menu-toggle">
                    <div id="hamburger">
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cross">
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu-hide">
                        <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                                        'container'      => '',
                                        'container_class' => 'menu-hidden',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'menu-hide',
                                        'menu_id'     => 'header_menu',
                                        ) );
                                ?>
                </nav>




            </header>
```

The css I am using to hide the dropdown is as follows

.menu-hide {

```
background-color: #666;
width: 100%;
height: 0px;
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
     -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        transition: height 0.5s linear;
```

}

.menu-hide.menu-open {

```
background-color: #666;
width: 100%;
height: calc(100vh - 70px);
-webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
     -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
        transition: height 0.5s linear;
```

}

I basically want to nest whatever menu list items there are in the nav with class menu-hide that is using a slidetoggle function so they behave with the same slide effect when the hamburger menu icon is clicked. The list items are still visible under the header

Iknow this is vague but I have googled for hours and not found anything relevant enough and just need pointing in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: I take it that all of the classes (.menu-hide, .menu-open) you expect to see are visible in the inspector?

Comment: yes they are all working, i have moved towards using the #header_menu tag and manipulating the class for list items to use an opacity transition and am moving forward with that using collapse etc... im not sure its the tidiest way to do it but the items i want to hide are collapsing and not affecting any other items on the page so seems like an okay fix?